# Change only home-page design

Tags: magento-1.9, home-page

I have one magento live store in working condition, but now client want to change whole home page design. so now I need to create new package or just new theme?I have html theme.

can any one suggest me? Or also tell me what is the best way to change only home-page design.

Comment: it majorly depends on how much changes you want  on home page. If there are no changes in any other page then you can change your homepage from admin and also add respective css or js file from there

Answer (score 0):

In `Design` section of CMS Page that is set for homepage you may achieve any layout customization imaginable

```
CMS->Pages->(homepage)->Design
```

Normally no template nor layout changes are needed in the codebase. But depending on complexity of changes you may still need to commit some CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the cms home page directly in the backend as suggested by Vladimir Samsonov or you can use the handle `cms_index_index` in a xml layout file.